# accordion menu stops working on adding href links

Tags: jquery, hover, href, accordion

Here my simple accordion :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $("dt.title").click(function()
    { 
      $("div.info").slideUp("slow"); 
      $(this).next("div.info:hidden").slideDown("normal" );
    });
});
</script>
```

And it works fine with the this html :

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container">

<ul id="nav">
<dt class="title"><a href="#">About</a></dt>
<dt class="title"><a href="#">Work</a></dt>
<div class="info">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Bol</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Annie</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Imran</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<dt class="title"><a href="#">Contact</a></dt>
<dt class="title"><a href="#">Links</a></dt>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I put the href links, the menu stops working. For example :

```
<dt class="title"><a href="about.html">About</a></dt>
```

Also tell me how can I add the active and hover state in the menu.

Comment: i think u need to let us know which javascript framework u using... jQuery?

Comment: Yes, I am using jQuery !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `return false`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $("dt.title").click(function(){ 
        $("div.info").slideUp("slow"); 
        $(this).next("div.info:hidden").slideDown("normal" );
        return false; //do it here
    });
});
</script>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container">

            <ul id="nav">
                <dt class="title"><a href="#">About</a></dt>
                <dt class="title"><a href="about.html">Work</a></dt>
                <div class="info">
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Bol</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Annie</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Imran</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <dt class="title"><a href="#">Contact</a></dt>
                <dt class="title"><a href="#">Links</a></dt>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you are planning to load the content of `about.html` in `content` element then use `load` method. Your function will be something like

```
    $("dt.title").click(function(){ 
        $("div.info").slideToggle("slow");
        $('#content').load($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
        return false;
    });
```

But this will not work for cross-domain url.

[UPDATE]

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//no use for this var
var loader = $("<div></div>").html('Loading')

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".title").click(function(){ 

        $(this).find("ul").slideToggle("slow");

        //do all the animations here
        //but using $.get, you will get more animation effect
        //I guess

        $('#content').load($(this).find('a').attr('href'));

        return false;
    });

    //similarly for inner link
    $(".title ul a").click(
        function ()
        {   
            $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));

            return false;
    }); 

});

</script>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">

    <ul id="nav">   
    <dt class="title"><a href="test.php">About</a>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="test.php">Bol</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.php">Annie Khalid</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.php">Imran</a></li>
        </ul>
    </dt>

    <dt class="title"><a href="test.php">Work</a>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="test.php">Bol</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.php">Annie Khalid</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.php">Imran</a></li>
        </ul>
    </dt>

    <dt class="title"><a href="test.php">Contact</a>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="test.php">Bol</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.php">Annie Khalid</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.php">Imran</a></li>
        </ul>

    </dt>    

    <dt class="title"><a href="test.php">Links</a>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="test.php">Bol</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.php">Annie Khalid</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.php">Imran</a></li>
        </ul>

    </dt>
    </ul>    

    </div>

    <div id="content">      
    <p>Welcome to my site!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</p>

    <p>In this tutorial we will be taking your average everyday website and enhancing it with jQuery.
     We will be adding ajax functionality so that the content loads into the relevant container instead
      of the user having to navigate to another page. We will also be integrating some awesome effects...
    </p>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried that but the the about page doesn't load. For example when i click on about the work menu slids up but about page doesn't load. Why is that ?

Comment: @Kashif Ejaz do you mean that you want to load the content of `about.html` in some div. I think you should do that using `load()` method

Comment: thanks for tell me that it is not possible that way. Please scroll down......ajax call works but not the menu. Have a look !

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are not preventing the browser from executing the request to the link. Therefor, it is treated as a link. You can either `return false;` at the end of you click function or replace the href attribute value dynamically(JavaScript) to `#`;

[EDIT]
This should work even though I haven't tested it. Hope it at least gives you the idea.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $("dt.title").click(function(){ 
      $("div.info").slideUp("slow"); 
      $(this).next("div.info:hidden").slideDown("normal" );
      return false;
    }).hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("hover");
      },function(){
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
    }).each(function(){
      $(this).attr("href","#");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I've added the code that SHOULD work but you should try some trial and error before asking for a copy/paste solution. I feel you learn better that way. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tired that but what it does it lets the menu work but the about page doesn't load.

Comment: You can't have the browser go to another page and expect the accordion to open. You can though either load the page through AJAX or instead of opening the accordion on the click event open it on the hover event.

[EDIT] OR you can let the browser go to the intended page and via PHP or javascript give a class to the current selected accordion element. Then through javascript open that accordion.